# Using extended ascii code as second string in file search using PHP

Tags: php, string, ascii

First things first. This was working and will still work if I pick a different string instead of the character in question.

The following code is being used to find all occurrences of a block of data needed within a file.  Each block starts with "3476 DSR" and ends with "Å".  The specifics for the character are:

DEC OCT HEX BIN      Symbol HTMLNumber HTMLName Description

197 305 C5  11000101 Å      \&#197\;     \&Aring\;  Latin capital letter A with ring above

The code is:

```
$path = 'report';
$file = $_POST['select'];
$filepath = $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file;

$report = file_get_contents($filepath,'r');

$string1 = "3476 DSR";
$string2 = "Å";

preg_match_all("(".preg_quote($string1).".*?".preg_quote($string2).")s",$report,$matches);


echo '<div class="output">';

foreach ($matches[0] as $value) {

echo "<pre>";
echo $value;
echo "</pre>";

}

echo '</div>';
```

This was working fine until it wasnt and under investigation I found the extended ascii character had been replaced somehow with what looked like a question mark inside an octagon.  After replacing the original character back, I still cannot get it to work.  If i use a different string for the ascii character, the code works fine, but does not give the the correct data obviously.

It has been difficult to find anything related to this and I have tried using the different identifiers above with no luck.

Does anybody know what might be the issue here?

Comment: Looks like you need to look for UTF-8 and why it matters. "Extended ASCII" can refer to any of the thousands of encodings people came up with, and they are _all_ superseded by Unicode. The question mark symbol you get indicates that your web server thinks you're using UTF-8 and it turns out you aren't.

Comment: The question mark was in my code, not returned by the web server. (not that you were saying it was.) Is this an issue of a web server setting or an issue with they way I am searching?  Essentially, do I need to be searching for unicode U+00C5 in some manner or is Searching for the "Å" fine, but a setting is wrong?

Comment: I am reading more about unicode, thanks for the lead, but the above clarification would help.

Comment: It's most likely an "issue" with your current editor, or the one you used to write the code with. There seems to be a mismatch between the encoding of your files and the encoding of your data source (in `$filepath`). You need to be looking for the character as it is represented in the contents of `$filepath`, as PHP does not convert between encodings by itself.

Comment: At any rate, it's not a good sign that you get the invalid character placeholder, as some editors might replace the underlying invalid code point with it (and obviously break your code even though it would work otherwise). If you know you other file's encoding and you know the byte value of that character, you can use the `\x**` notation to represent it instead (so if the byte value is `C5`, that would be `\xC5`).

Comment: zneak.  You fixed it.  \xC5 works and so does using vim.  The editor is the issue.  Thanks for the lead on character encoding.

Comment: the convention on Stack Overflow is that answers are, well, in the answer section, so I duplicated my helping comment there. Since it solved your problem, you should consider clicking the checkmark under its score. Also, if I missed anything, feel free to comment/edit the answer.

Comment: Did know how to do that. Checked the check!! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the editor you're using (rightfully, in my opinion) expects your file to be UTF-8. Since it is not, it replaced your character with the "missing character" placeholder, which has a different binary value, and as such you wouldn't find it anymore in your document.

Since you know the binary value you expect your character to have (0xC5), you can use the hex escaping sequence `\xC5` to represent it in your source file without having to worry that an editor expecting Unicode will slaughter it.